# Role-based authentication for OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

In addition to bearer token authentication, I am also trying to validate user roles/authorities to ensure that they are permitted to access this resource. Here is what I have so far:

```html
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${oauth.enabled}")
    boolean oauthEnabled;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-uri}")
    String introspectionUri;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-client-id}")
    String clientId;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.opaque.introspection-client-secret}")
    String clientSecret;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (oauthEnabled) {
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and().cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests(urlRegistry -> urlRegistry
                            .antMatchers("/api/health").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(resourceServer -> resourceServer
                            .opaqueToken(opaqueToken -> opaqueToken
                                    .introspectionUri(this.introspectionUri)
                                    .introspectionClientCredentials(this.clientId, this.clientSecret)
                            )
                    );
}

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@ControllerAdvice
@CrossOrigin(originPatterns = "*")
public class InventoryCountdownController extends BaseController {

    @GetMapping("/icd")
    //@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SOME_USER_ROLE')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Countdown>> getIcd(@RequestParam(value = "val") String val) {
        ...
    }
```

The problem that I am running into is that I am getting back "Unexpected error: Access is denied". When I replace the "hasAuthority" annotation with `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")`, it seems to work fine. What am I missing?

As per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide, I am using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` to implement my resource server.

Comment: If you have class which implements `PermissionEvaluator`, make sure its returning true for  user which have `SOME_USER_ROLE` from `hashPermission( ... )` which is method of `PermissionEvaluator`.

Comment: Make sure you don't mix PERMISSION with ROLE, those are different concepts.

Comment: I don't have a class that implements `PermissionEvaluator` Do I need this? Is it similar to the old `OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler`?

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is to populate the authorities based on the `"scope"` attribute that is typically included in the response from the introspection endpoint.

For example, if the introspection endpoint responds with `{ …​, "scope" : "messages"}` then the authority list will be `["SCOPE_messages"]`.

You can customise this using a custom `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` and exposing it as a bean.

```java
@Bean
public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
    return new CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector();
}
```

where `CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector` will look similar to this

```java
public class CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
    private OpaqueTokenIntrospector delegate =
            new NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector("https://idp.example.org/introspect", "client", "secret");

    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal = this.delegate.introspect(token);
        return new DefaultOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal(
                principal.getName(), principal.getAttributes(), extractAuthorities(principal));
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal) {
        List<String> scopes = principal.getAttribute(OAuth2IntrospectionClaimNames.SCOPE);
        return scopes.stream()
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This is all described in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-authorization-extraction).

Answer (score 0):

the client et secret should be the credentials of the front application or the backend( resource server). should I store in the resource server th cient id ans secret of all clients that are calling my rest api

Comment: This is question, not answer. Please delete it and add comment to issue question/answer

Comment: This is not answer. Please delete it and add comment instead